# WPF ListView padding on header columns

Tags: wpf, listview

Hi there im using a ListView in wpf and have a few columns that have auto width, now i want some padding on them but im a bit unsure how to do this? i have a red background on my header and then text in there, but i want to have some space between the border of the box and the text...

[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could modify the `HeaderTemplate` of the `GridViewColumn`

```
<GridViewColumn ...>
    <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Some Header" Background="Red" />
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: Can you reuse this template across multiple ``GridViewColumnHeader`` elements?

Comment: @malthe I think you can declare this as a style and then bind it to each column header. I'm attempting this now.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else coming across this, here is an option that's a little cleaner. Not specifying a key on the style has this apply to all columns. This also uses padding, like the OP wanted.

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,0" />
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```